# UncaughtException when loading SVF2 models on Chrome

Tags: autodesk-forge

Since yesterday, my app is encountering an error, and I'm not sure what it is until now.
As soon as I load a model, an "uncaughtException" occurs.

Error message:

```
  uncaughtException
  Error: read ETIMEDOUT
  at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20) 
  {
      errno: -60,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'read'
  }
```

The error only occurs with models that have been translated into SVF2. The viewer loads the svf-version of the model. 
The error only occurs with Chrome and not with Firefox and Safari.

I have the extract same version live running on azure and everything works fine with all browsers.

Two days ago everything worked, since then I have only updated the VSCode version from 1.51.1 to to 1.52 as well as my operating system macOS from 11.01 to 11.1.

Systemdaten:
Forge Viewer V7.33.1
MacOS BigSur 11.1
VSCode 1.52
NodeLTS: 14.15.3

Anybody have any idea?

UPDATE:
I think I have found an explanation.
The error occurs with all models that have been translated to SVF2. 
For translating I have tried 2 methods:

1. forge-apis v0.8.3 (according to manifest the translation was successful, but the model can not be loaded in viewer in SVF2 format)(cloud credits were consumed during translation process).
2. With VSCode-Forge-Tools from Petr Broz (the manifest looks exactly the same as the one with method 1, but here the model can be loaded in the viewer in SVF2 format)(no cloud credits were consumed during translation process).

UPDATE 2:
SVF2 translation code snippet.

```
  const input = Object.assign(
    { urn },
    data.compressedUrn
      ? {
          compressedUrn: data.compressedUrn,
          rootFilename: data.rootFilename,
        }
      : null
  );
  // Can use SVF2 (OTG): type: 'svf2'
  const payload = {
    input,
    output: {
      force: true,
      formats: [
        {
          views: ["2d", "3d"],
          type: "svf2",
        },
      ],
    },
  };
const token =  await getToken();
this.derivativesAPI.translate(
      payload,
      {
        xAdsForce: payload.output.force,
      },
      { autoRefresh: false },
      token
    );
```

Comment: The error message you shared looks like a backend issue from your server app. Not from the viewer's side. Please try to use a simple viewer app (saying an HTML file containing the simplest viewer codes) to load your SVF2 model to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: About the cloud credits consumption, it depends on how you trigger the SVF2 translation. is it `Raw model file -> SVF1 -> SVF2` or `Raw model file -> SVF2`?

Comment: the error is fixed.  I have not changed anything, except tested it in several Wifis. Maybe it was an internal error, I don't know.

Comment: About the cloud credits consumption: The translation was from Raw model file -> SVF2

Comment: I'm double-checking with our team, please bear with me. Will get you back A.S.A.P.

Comment: Could you share a code snippet demonstrating how you trigger SVF2 translation with [orge-api-nodejs-client](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client)? Since SVF2 is under public beta currently, we will NOT change for SVF2 translation if you request SVF2 only. However, SVF2 translation will consume cloud credits once it's out of beta (GA release) in the future.

Comment: I updated my original question @EasonKang
I am using the same code for translation to svf, i just changed the output formats type.

Comment: Hi FlorolF, sorry for missing your message. I have some priority assignments to deal with in. my work queue. Your code looks fine. For better tracking this issue, could you consider forwarding it to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com with your urn and the request & response your passed/obtained from the `DerivativeApi#translation`?

Comment: Here is a test sample for you: https://github.com/yiskang/forge-viewmodels-nodejs-svf2